# How to export all pages from MediaWiki to hierarchy of HTML files

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I'm in the process of starting my bachelor project and needs a documentation system. Currently it looks like MediaWiki fulfills my requirements. All pages of a particular MediaWiki-project is stored in a separate database system. Does it exist an easy way for extracting these pages to a HTML-hierarchy of files? Will it be easier to go for e.g. DokuWiki that doesn't support database functionality?

Comment: @MichaelJ.W.Beijer I have written a python script a couple of months ago, and I have added a new answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Will try it now.

Comment: see also: [Obtaining static HTML files from Wikipedia XML dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713330/obtaining-static-html-files-from-wikipedia-xml-dump)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the [DumpHTML Extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDumpHTML) does what you're looking for? This tool should dump your entire wiki as HTML.

Comment: This is no longer a viable solution as it wasn't maintained for a long time and has now been archived. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149509/301725 answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the task to export a small MediaWiki to HTML.

I wrote a script in Python.

It is not perfect, but covers links between the pages even with anchors and links to non-existing pages, images, thumbnails, and even supports authentication for dumping a protected wiki.

You can find it here, under MIT license:
https://github.com/SolidCharity/exportMediaWiki2HTML

Comment: Hi there, trying it, but have run into the following error:

    PS C:\exportMediaWiki2HTML> ./exportMediaWiki2Html.py 
    https://beijer.uk/index.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
    File "C:\exportMediaWiki2HTML\exportMediaWiki2Html.py", line 8, in <module>
    from urllib import parse

    ImportError: cannot import name parse

----

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I have like zero knowledge of Python, btw. Can barely manage AutoHotkey ;-)

Comment: @MichaelJ.W.Beijer Good point, I have now added instructions for installing the requirements: https://github.com/SolidCharity/exportMediaWiki2HTML#install

I am not so sure how Python works on Windows, I have always run Python on Linux.

Make sure you are using Python3, and you run `pip install requests`

By the way, the parameter should not be the url to an html file, but the url of your MediaWiki instance, wg. `https://mywiki.example.org`

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I needed! Have my upvote! Should be the accept answer to date!